# Run a sql query multiple times concurrently in python

Tags: python, postgresql, multiprocessing

I am trying to execute a sql statement multiple times concurrently using multiprocessing library.
Here is the script I am using,

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
import psycopg2

rec = []
def make_query(connection):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    print("conn: %s curs:%s pid=%s" % (id(connection), id(cursor), os.getpid()))
    postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from users"
    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
    records = cursor.fetchall() 

    for row in records:
        rec.append(row[0])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres", password="password", host="127.0.0.1", port="5432", database="abc")
    #cursor = connection.cursor()
    pool = Pool()
    start_time = time.time()
    for _ in range(1000):
        pool.apply_async(make_query, (connection,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(rec)
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

and this is the response I am getting,

```
[]
--- 0.48270273208618164 seconds ---
```

am I doing anything wrong here, because I am not able to access any records. But **users** table has thousands of records.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `multiprocessing`. When you spawn a different process, it won't share data back to its parent, so when you do `rec.append(row[0])`, you're appending that value into the `rec` list in that particular process. Then once the process finishes evaluating, its memory is discarded.

If you want to share state between processes, there are [several primitives available](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes), but the best way is to return data from each process and combine it within the outer function.

```
result_tasks = []
for _ in range(1000):
    result_tasks.append(pool.apply_async(make_query, (connection,)))
result = [res.get() for res in result_tasks]
```